# How to reset Time.time in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a problem with the timer in my first game and I want to know if it's possible to reset Time.time to start from 00.00 again if I moved to another scene?

Comment: Why would you need to reset it? (as far as I know you can't) Why not simply store a start time and "count" from there? (And please keep in mind not all "Unity" tags are related to Unity3D. Read their tag wikis to see what they are about. [unity] is not about [unity3d] for example)

Comment: Could you use [`Time.timeSinceLevelLoad`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Time-timeSinceLevelLoad.html)?

Comment: @rutter : Yes this is work ; the timer starts again from 0 when the level is reloaded . Thank u :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "timeSinceLevelLoad" because it gives you the time in seconds of the last level loaded.

Hope this helps!